# Should I use StructureMap or Session to manage a concrete instance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I am using StructureMap on an ASP.NET MVC project. I have an object that I want to use throughout the session. Should I use StructureMap or Session:["MyObject"] to manage the concrete instance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on your scenario. If this instance is tied to a particular user and should not be shared between other users you should use `Session`. For example use `Session` to store products that the user added to his cart in an e-commerce application.

If it is for injecting dependencies such as repositories into your controllers and managing controllers `StructureMap` is fine.

Comment: The instance is tied to a particular user and should not be shared between other users. I know that Session will work. However, I think that the same thing can be done with StructureMap by setting the appropriate CacheBy value. Is there any advantage to using StructureMap over the Session object? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any advantage of using StructureMap for storing objects into session. Also his would make your session management code tied to a particular framework and probably more difficult to unit test. Of course without seeing actual code everything is speculation and words in the air.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll just use Session.